# Nested dictionary structure's permutation to List of Dictionary keeping same structure in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, permutation

I have following JSON/Dictionary Structure.

```
{
    "layers": [{
            "type": "fc",
            "name": "fc1",
            "nodes": [100, 200],
            "activation": "relu",
            "dropout": false
        }, {
            "type": "fc",
            "name": "fc2",
            "nodes": 50,
            "activation": ["relu", "tanh"],
            "dropout": false
        }
    ],
    "hyper_parameters": {
        "dropout": [0.25, 0.30],
        "lr": [0.01, 0.002, 0.5],
        "lr_decay": 1,
        "epochs": 100,
        "epoch_no_imprv": 10,
        "batch_size": 100
    }
}
```

I want to generate All the permutations of above structure, wherever there is a **list**, preserving the same structure.
so above structure should generate list of 24 such structure.
Showing sample 4 structures below.

```
[
    {
        "layers": [{
                "type": "fc",
                "name": "fc1",
                "nodes": 100,
                "activation": "relu",
                "dropout": false
            }, {
                "type": "fc",
                "name": "fc2",
                "nodes": 50,
                "activation": "relu",
                "dropout": false
            }
        ],
        "hyper_parameters": {
            "dropout": 0.25,
            "lr": 0.01,
            "lr_decay": 1,
            "epochs": 100,
            "epoch_no_imprv": 10,
            "batch_size": 100
        }
    },
    {
        "layers": [{
                "type": "fc",
                "name": "fc1",
                "nodes": 200,
                "activation": "relu",
                "dropout": false
            }, {
                "type": "fc",
                "name": "fc2",
                "nodes": 50,
                "activation": "relu",
                "dropout": false
            }
        ],
        "hyper_parameters": {
            "dropout": 0.25,
            "lr": 0.01,
            "lr_decay": 1,
            "epochs": 100,
            "epoch_no_imprv": 10,
            "batch_size": 100
        }
    },
    {
        "layers": [{
                "type": "fc",
                "name": "fc1",
                "nodes": 100,
                "activation": "relu",
                "dropout": false
            }, {
                "type": "fc",
                "name": "fc2",
                "nodes": 50,
                "activation": "tanh",
                "dropout": false
            }
        ],
        "hyper_parameters": {
            "dropout": 0.25,
            "lr": 0.01,
            "lr_decay": 1,
            "epochs": 100,
            "epoch_no_imprv": 10,
            "batch_size": 100
        }
    },
    {
        "layers": [{
                "type": "fc",
                "name": "fc1",
                "nodes": 200,
                "activation": "relu",
                "dropout": false
            }, {
                "type": "fc",
                "name": "fc2",
                "nodes": 50,
                "activation": "tanh",
                "dropout": false
            }
        ],
        "hyper_parameters": {
            "dropout": 0.25,
            "lr": 0.01,
            "lr_decay": 1,
            "epochs": 100,
            "epoch_no_imprv": 10,
            "batch_size": 100
        }
    }
]
```

here, following keys can have list, but i would prefer if it can be made generic enough

**nodes, activation, dropout,lr.**

And "layers" list can have any number of layers.

Any other simplified structure to achieve the same thing will also work.

Comment: "above structure should generate list of 18 such structure" - maybe I am missing something, but shouldn't it be 24 rather than 18 in your example?

Comment: Yup!! my bad. corrected in the question. Thanks for pointing it out.